# project hosted on firebase rtmp server is running but rtmp protocol not working

Tags: hosting, firebase-hosting, rtmp, node-media-server, nginx-rtmp

rtmp server working on local machine and I can do video streaming on local network but rtmp server not working on global network

I am working on live video streaming project I have used nod-media-server library in project
when I run my project on local machine then it works correctly and I  can do live streaming on local network
but now I have deployed this project to firebase and render.com server and on both servers https request apis are works correctly but rtmp protocol apis doesn't work
its because rtmp server is not setup in firebase and render.com

so I am asking how to setup rtmp server on firebase or render.com